# Linux cp command to copy folders: copy content of the folder vs copy folder

Tags: linux, bash

How to understand whether `cp` will copy the content of the folder or the folder itself.
For example, I have a file `/some/path/text.txt`.
If I do `cp -r /some/path /another/path2`, the new path of the file will be `/another/path2/text.txt`?
If I do `cp -r /some/path/ /another/path2`, the new path is `/another/path2/text.txt`?
If I do `cp -r /some/path/ /another/path2/`, what will happen?
If I do `cp -r /some/path /another/path2/`, what will happen?
I'm always confused about this and many times I correct my wrong copying. I tried to find information about this but didn't find any structured information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases it doesn't matter. Instead, 'cp' decides based on whether the destination exists.

Assuming the source is always a directory, and you're using either `cp -r` or `cp -a`:

1. **If the source is a *symlink* to a directory,** then the trailing slash after the source is important. Without it, you'd be only copying the symlink *itself* and not the directory it points to.

   If the source isn't a symlink, the trailing slash after the source doesn't matter to 'cp'.
2. **If the target points to an existing directory,** then the *whole* source directory will be copied into the target. That is, `cp -r abc def` will cause `def/abc/text.txt` to be created. Trailing slashes on the source nor the destination do not matter.

   If the target doesn't exist, then the source directory will be copied *as* the target. That is, `cp -r abc def` will only create `def/text.txt`. Trailing slashes don't affect anything here, either.

The 2nd "rule" can be annoying, as it seems like you cannot copy an existing directory's *contents* directly into another directory without resorting to something like `abc/*` (which will miss hidden files), etc.

However, an easy way to achieve that is to specify `.` as the last path component – this will trick cp into "creating" a `.` in the destination:

```
cp -r /some/path/. /another/path
```

Trailing slash on the destination still doesn't matter.

(Note that these rules are not universal for all programs; in particular, **rsync behaves differently** and trailing slashes indeed tell it whether to copy the whole directory or only its contents.)

---

**In short:**

- If you want to copy the directory *whole,* ensure the destination already exists (pre-create it using mkdir).
- If you want to copy the directory's *contents,* make sure to end the source with `/.` (slash + dot) (like the website).